# Download a PDF after clicking a button | VS Code says 'Cannot find name 'download'" | using pdf-lib library

Tags: pdf-lib.js

I'm using pdf-lib for PDF documents. I'm starting with a simple goal: user clicks a button and downloads a PDF. It's working, but VS Code is underlining the word download in red and saying "Cannot find name 'download'" from this line:

download(pdfBytes, "pdf-lib_creation_example.pdf", "application/pdf");

screenshot

[image: 1]

I downloaded the npm package for downloadjs (1.4.7), so I'm not sure why VS Code isn't recognizing it.

Here's the full code for the page (using SvelteKit):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib@1.4.0"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/downloadjs@1.4.7"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Click the button to create a new PDF document with <code>pdf-lib</code></p>
    <button on:click={createPdf}>Create PDF</button>
    <p class="small">(Your browser will download the resulting file)</p>
  </body>

<script>
  import { PDFDocument, StandardFonts, rgb, } from 'pdf-lib';

    async function createPdf() {
      // Create a new PDFDocument
      const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.create()

      // Embed the Times Roman font
      const timesRomanFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.TimesRoman)

      // Add a blank page to the document
      const page = pdfDoc.addPage()

      // Get the width and height of the page
      const { width, height } = page.getSize()

      // Draw a string of text toward the top of the page
      const fontSize = 30
      page.drawText('Creating PDFs in JavaScript is awesome!', {
        x: 50,
        y: height - 4 * fontSize,
        size: fontSize,
        font: timesRomanFont,
        color: rgb(0, 0.53, 0.71),
      })

      // Serialize the PDFDocument to bytes (a Uint8Array)
      const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save()

      // Trigger the browser to download the PDF document
      download(pdfBytes, "pdf-lib_creation_example.pdf", "application/pdf");
    }

</script>

<style>
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px;
}

.small {
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px;
}

button {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}
</style>
```

Tried rearranging my page code to make sure it wasn't a scope issue. I've been searching on Google for a long time. No videos that cover this type of situation that I can find.

Comment: When I comment out that download line it doesn't work. I click the button and nothing happens.

Comment: I appreciate your time looking into it! I have a lot to learn about the technology / processes involved with documents and downloading.